# How do I install Symfony 1.4 using composer?

Tags: symfony-1.4, composer-php

I have some legacy Symfony 1.4 projects which I'd like to enhance with a composer.json file for their dependencies.

I've managed to configure composer to use the "plugins" directory as opposed to "vendors".  However according to the Symfony 1.4 documentation, the library ideally should live in "lib/vendor" off of my project root.

If I were to configure a custom repository-package pointing to the latest 1.4.x svn in my composer.json, how would I get it so that it installs to "lib/vendor"?

Comment: I'd imagine that'd be difficult, especially with the composer auto loading expecting your code to follow the PSR-0 standard.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In fact, this is not really a problem to have symfony outside `lib/vendor`. It's recommended to have it in this folder path because, that way, it will be automatically loaded.
Using `vendor-dir` in Composer, you can configure where to put your vendor library. But this is a configuration set as *root-only*, so it can't be configured per require library (at least I think so).

But you can put symfony in your `plugins/` directory and then say to your app you want to autoload everything here, using `apps/frontend/config/autoload.yml`:

```
autoload:
  symfony:
    path:      %SF_PLUGIN_DIR%/symfony/lib
    recursive: on
```

Do not forget to change the path in your `config/ProjectConfiguration.class.php`:

```
<?php

require_once dirname(__FILE__).'/../plugins/symfony/lib/autoload/sfCoreAutoload.class.php';
```

That should do the trick.

Comment: @Omega Is the entry on autoload.yml file really necessary?

Comment: @Restless nope, it's not necessary

Comment: I was trying this out and it seemed that way. Thanks for the confirmation @j0k

Answer (score 1):

You can write your own [composer installer](http://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/custom-installers.md).